# Create a class with commonly-used methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, scope

I would like to create a file containing methods I will use many times.

Let's say in Javascript I want to create a "methods" file, I will create a file called functions.js, and write my functions on it, like the following

functions.js:

```
function myAlert(message){
      alert(message);
}
```

If I include this file in my HTML head, I can call `mAlert()` from anywhere as long as I have included functions.js

Is there a way to do a similar thing in Objective-C?

Wich file should be created, and where/how to include them, and how to call the methods?

Comment: Probably you should start here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html

Comment: Make functions, not a class.

Comment: Your subject says methods, but then your example code lists C functions. They are different. C functions don't have to exist in a particular class.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of choices.

Classes can include class methods, which are performed by the class itself instead of an instance of the class. You declare a class method with a "+" instead of a "-" at the beginning:

```
+ (void) aClassMethod;
```

Then you call it using the name of the class:

```
[MyClass aClassMethod];
```

As long as a given file has imported the header for MyClass, you can call that class method.

The problem with this approach is that since it's a class method, it does not have access to storing state data in instance variables.

The other option is to make your "Methods" class a singleton class. You can then call instance methods in your singleton anywhere:

```
[[Methods sharedMethods]  myAlertWithString: @"message"];
```

Do a search here on SO on the singleton design pattern in Cocoa. There are quite a few examples.

Comment: I will check how to create a singleton class , and let you know how it's going (tomorow cause it is late here). thank you

Answer (score 2):

We can use singleton pattern.

.h

```
@interface CommonFunctions : NSObject
+(CommonFunctions)shareInstance;
-(void)someFunction:(Class*)parameter;
 ...
 @end
```

.m

```
+(CommonFunctions *)shareInstance {
   static CommonFunctions *_shareInstance = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _sharedClient = [[RESTClient alloc] init]];
 });

 return _shareInstance;
}

-(void)someFunction:(Class*)parameter
{
}
```

Then we just call this function like:

> [[CommonFunctions shareInstance] someFunction:parameter]

Answer (score 1):

You can use c code in your project anywhere you would like, so a single .cpp file and .h file can be used to create globally accessible functions.

I, personally, have a class that I setup my global methods in.

.h

```
@interface CommonFunctions : NSObject

+(void)someFunction:(Class*)parameter;

...

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation CommonFunctions

+(void)someFunction:(Class*)parameter
{
    //Do something commonly used with this parameter
}

@end
```

Then I just call this function like:

```
[CommonFunctions someFunction:parameter];
```

Comment: These aren't functions; they are methods.

Comment: Is this an exemple of the singleton class? Can you explain me why you declare twice the function in both file? Thank you

PS: Then do you have to import the .h and .m in the file you want to use it?

Comment: @user3312399: In objectiveC, we have 2 file .h and .m
In file .h, we declare function name for another class can see it.
In file .m, we write function/method body.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, you don't have to use classes. Just use plain old C, it will work just fine. Making a pointless class just to hold a hodgepodge of functions is bad style.

Remember that you can add methods to existing classes. If you want a method that could belong to NSDictionary, you just add it to the class.